# Output resulting in name of project instead of enumType?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get user to choose from the enum list then get an output based on the input using Switch.

What would be the most efficient way of using enum in this case?

```
namespace enum_assignment
{
   class Program
  {
    enum transportation
    { Car = 20,
      Cab = 10,
      Bus = 5,
      Bicycle = 3,
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Kelvin Transit Center");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Type enumType;
        enumType = typeof(transportation);

        Console.WriteLine("Available transit methods:{0}", Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} dollars", Enum.GetName(enumType, value), value);

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your method of transporatation: Car,Bus,Cab,Bicycle");
        Console.ReadLine();


        transportation defaultMthd = transportation.Bicycle;
        foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(enumType))

        switch(defaultMthd)
        {
            case transportation.Bicycle:
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for choosing {0},it is {1} every hour.",enumType, value);
            break;

            case transportation.Bus:
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for choosing {0},it is {1} every hour.",enumType, value);
            break;

            case transportation.Cab:
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for choosing {0},it is {1} every hour.",enumType, value);
            break;

            case transportation.Car:
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for choosing {0},it is {1} every hour.",enumType, value);
            break;
        }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code? Did you try to debug the code? You are asking user to enter the method of transportation but you are not saving the value entered by the user anywhere...

Comment: You have not used the value you got from `Console.ReadLine`

Comment: Also note your switch does nothing at all because in every case you execute the exact same code, not that it fixed your issue but removing a lot of code can help you find the issue yourself, if you remove the whole switch block and replace it with just Console.WriteLine("Thank you for choosing {0},it is {1} every hour.",enumType, value); then you'll have the exact same thing as you have now

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the user's input:

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then parse it to get the method that was chosen:

```
transportation method = (transportation)Enum.Parse(enumType, userInput);
```

Then when you print it, print out the user input again:

```
Console.WriteLine("Thank you for choosing {0},it is {1} every hour.", userInput, value);
```

Once you have this working, you may find that the program crashes if the user enters an invalid input. In that case you'll want to look at [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx). I'll leave the rest for you to work out.